# /system/bin/screencap is not working with emulator with option "-no-window"

Tags: android-emulator, android-source

I was build AOSP and generate emulator on remote computer.
For the reason, I have to launch the emulator with “-no-window” option.
(Without the option, the emulator is failed to launch with error text “no available vide device”)

[terminal 0 (Launch an emulator)]

> emulator -no-window -noaudio

[terminal 1 (Attach to it)]

> adb -s emulator-554 shell

Then, /system/bin/screencap is not working correctly that it generate empty 320x480 image.
Is there any way to take screen a capture with the option?
Or, the idea to launch the emulator without “-no-window” option in spite of I launch it remotely is very welcome.
(For example, force to recognize a dummy screen to the emulator)

Thanks for your big helps!

Comment: No, you will not be able to capture the screen with the "-no-window" option as there is nothing to capture. When you launch it in that manner the system will not draw anything to a screen and thus your screen caps also do not contain anything.

Comment: You may need to give the headless system a display, either via some framebuffer driver, X11 tunneled through ssh, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks all. I will consider it.